DisplayInternalUICondition doesn't work correctly Wix 4
I upgraded Wix Bootstrapper project to WIX 4.0.0. And I have problems with displaying internal UI. The only problem is when uninstalling the application. I want the internal UI of msi package not to be shown. With Wix 3 there were no such problems, everything worked properly. Tell me how I can solve this problem, please.
This is the code before upgrading to WIX 4 and everything worked fine.
<MsiPackage Id="Setup" SourceFile="$(var.Setup.TargetPath)" Compressed="yes">
    <MsiProperty Name="AddDesktopShortcut" Value="[AddDesktopShortcutMsiVariable]" />
    <MsiProperty Name="INSTALLFOLDER" Value="[InstallFolder]" />
</MsiPackage>

<MsiPackage DisplayInternalUI="no" Id="SetupMSI" ForcePerMachine="yes" 
                     SourceFile="$(var.TargetDir)\......x64.msi" Compressed="yes">
</MsiPackage>

And this is the code after the update(Wix 4.0.0)
<MsiPackage Id="Setup" SourceFile="$(var.Setup.TargetPath)" Compressed="yes">
    <MsiProperty Name="AddDesktopShortcut" Value="[AddDesktopShortcutMsiVariable]" />
    <MsiProperty Name="INSTALLFOLDER" Value="[InstallFolder]" />
</MsiPackage>

<MsiPackage bal:DisplayInternalUICondition="no" Id="SetupMSI" ForcePerMachine="yes" 
                  SourceFile="$(var.TargetDir)\......x64.msi" Compressed="yes">
</MsiPackage>

And now when I uninstall the application, this dialog box appears. It shouldn't appear. I think bal:DisplayInternalUICondition="no" doesn't work. I tried bal:DisplayInternalUICondition="0" and it doesn't work too. And I tried to remove ......x64.msi using the command line by running the command (msiexec.exe /x "C:****.msi" /qn). It uninstalls silently in the background without displaying any windows.
Actual Result
There is dialog window FileInUse.
enter image description here
Expected Result
There are no windows. Uninstall successfully completed.
enter image description here

That UI isn't the internal MSI UI, that's the Bundle UI. It looks the Files In Use feature kicks in during uninstall in v4. Some people might consider that a beneficial feature in v4.

Thanks for the answer! Tell me what I need to add to the Bundle so that the FilesInUse dialog is not displayed?

I'm stuck, I don't know how to fix it, tell me what needs to be changed in the Bundle or done so that the FilesInUse dialog is not displayed? I use WixStandardBootstrapperApplication
